# Showing a popup after 3 seconds from page load in GatsbyJS (ReactJS) using the hook useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, popup, gatsby, use-effect

I have a Gatsby JS based website and I am trying to achieve the loading of a modal/popup after 3 seconds after the index page has loaded.

Here is my code so far:

*index.js*

```
const HomePage = ({ data }) => {

  const { t } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => <Modal
    component={<FormA />}
   />, 3000);

  }, []);

  return (

     <Layout>
       ...
     </Layout>
  )
}
```

*modal.js*

```
const Modal = (props) => {

return (

    <div className='modal'>
        <div className="modal-background"></div>
        <div className="modal-content">{props.component}</div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Modal
```

No error is detected, but the modal does not show up.

Any clue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Modal` does not show up because you are not returning it inside JSX from your component. Returning `Modal` from the callback function of `setTimeout` is useless.

To achieve the desired result, create a state in your component that is initially set to false.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
```

Then inside the `useEffect` hook, set it to `true` after three seconds.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => showModal(true), 3000);
}, []);
```

Now to show the modal, conditionally render it in your component's JSX.

```
return (
   <Layout>
     { showModal ? <Modal/> : null }
     ...
   </Layout>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a local state variable, which will be initially **false** and after component mounts we will make that variable **true** and we will clear the timeout when component unmounts.

```
function HomePage() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => setShowModal(true), 3000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeId)
  })

  return (
     <Layout>
        {showModal && <Modal />}
     </Layout>
  )
}
```

One suggestion which you can do is, make your Modal component take a prop like **showModal** which will return null, when **showModal** will be false.

```
 function Modal({ showModal }) {
  if(!showModal) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <div>Your Modal</div>
  )
}
```

and you can use it like this:-

```
  function HomePage() {
      const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const timeId = setTimeout(() => setShowModal(true), 3000)
    
        return () => clearTimeout(timeId)
      })
    
      return (
         <Layout>
            <Modal showModal={showModal} />
         </Layout>
      )
    }
```